# How do I add a buddy to more than one group in OS X Messages.app?

Tags: macos, messages, xmpp

When sorting buddies for XMPP services (not iMessage) into different groups in the contacts window in Messages.app for OS X I can click and drag one buddy from one group to another. However this removes the 'buddy' or contact from the previous group. How do I add a buddy to two groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Messages (Mavericks): Use buddy lists](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH15057) Apple support article explains how to add a contact to more than one group:

> Add a buddy to more than one group:   Press Option and drag the buddy
>   to each additional group.

Hat tip to @DaveDelong.